# Can i join output of "Describe" queries with other tables in snowflake

Tags: information-schema, snowflake

I trying to use the [Describe table](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/desc-table.html) in more complex way, thing like join with other tables , or other sql manipulation.

On the other hand it's look that snowflake not accept the [Describe table](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/desc-table.html) as subquery.

as example this is produce syntax error

```
select * from (DESC TABLE my_table) // syntax error line 1 at position 12 unexpected 'TABLE'.
```

Is there any way to do this?

(using the information_schema is not an option as it to much slow)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible with the result_scan() function. It takes query id as a parameter.

```
DESC TABLE my_table;
SELECT * FROM TABLE(RESULT_SCAN(LAST_QUERY_ID()));
```

More examples here:
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/result_scan.html